# WPF - 2D Image to 3D

Tags: wpf, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit

Hello I try to create 3D Map from 2D Bitmap Image. I have an image like [this.](https://ibb.co/xH5JT1n) Black pixels are wall. And this pixels have constant height. It is not a depth image and there is no different height.

Now I tried conventional method.

```
    void Map_2D_to_3D(Image<Bgr,Byte> map_image)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < map_image.Height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < map_image.Width; j++)
            {
                Bgr pixel_color = map_image[i, j];
                if (pixel_color.Blue == 0 && pixel_color.Red == 0 && pixel_color.Green == 0)
                {
                    View3D.Children.Add(helper_box.Create_Helper_Box(2, 2, 2, i * 2, j * 2, 2, Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 255)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In XAML

```
    <Grid x:Name="grid_3D" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="1">
        <h:HelixViewport3D x:Name="View3D" >
            <h:DefaultLights/>               
        </h:HelixViewport3D>
    </Grid>
```

In for loop I add a cube for an each pixel. And result is like [this.](https://ibb.co/2WKqX8v)

But in this method I create more than 400 different cube. So this was very slow. It is hard to zoom and rotate this map because of performance issue.

If I use bigger object for 3D conversion, performance is improving but for this method I have to use image segmentation algorithm for detecting circle, polygon shapes.

Could you help me for this problem? Thank you in advance.

> P.S. : I'm using Helix-3d-Toolkit in WPF for 3D view.

Comment: This question will probably get flagged for being too broad, but if I were doing this I'd probably create a single mesh using [the Marching Squares algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares). If possible I'd also implement it in conjunction with a [Point In Polygon algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) to fill in the shapes; no point creating geometry for the interiors if the user can't actually go there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can still use your 2D map as Height map, create a grid mesh according to your grid resolution on XZ plane, change the vertex Y position according to your map data. Then it will be a single mesh instead of many boxes.